# How to always run specific python script on windows server manager 2016

Tags: python, windows, server

i am new to the community and new in using servers and could use some help.

I am trying to setup an automatic JSON parser to another server using http post calls. The idea is as follows:

1. I manually put JSON files into a folder Input on the server
2. A python script that is always running on the server reads the files located within the folder
3. It reads the JSON files, posts all objects to another server, and moves the files to a "Processed" folder one file at a time.

I have been given a Windows Server, with Windows Server Manager 2016, and have managed to do the following:

- installed python 3.8.2. on the windows server
- able to run a python script using powershell
- Installed NSSM to create a windows service

Now the windows server manager says i cannot resume or start the service that i tried to install via NSSM.

I am very new to servers, as well as python itself. Can somebody help me to get a python script running 24/7 on a windows server with windows server manager 2016?

Edit:
I managed to create a python script that can read files, upload them and move them to a processed folder, but i still have to run it by myself while i want it to always run on the server

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You are trying a lot when you just first start with Python. I would suggest to start with a simpler problem first and build from there. Try first some code that reads the json files, processes it and moves the files to another folder. Once you have that sorted go figure out what to do with the NSSM.

Comment: I already have a working code that reads JSON files, processes it and moves the files to another folder. Only the always running on an external windows server is the issue, ill revise my question